# How do I get LaTeX to perform an exponential regression?

Tags: math-mode, graphics, plot, statistics

I have been trying to get some regressions for my estimates, but there seems to be only content on polynomial and linear regression. This is the code I use for linear:

```
  \begin{center}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{\textbf{Regressão Linear do Período de Crescimento}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{width=10cm,
        compat=1.3,
        legend style={font=\footnotesize}}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={Ano},
    ylabel={População},
    legend cell align=left,
    legend pos=north west]
    \addplot[only marks] table[row sep=\\]{
        X Y\\ %remover estimativas de complemento
-700    80\\
-400    300\\
-200    300\\
-100    600\\
1       1250\\
100     1500\\
    };
    \addlegendentry{Estimativas}
    \addplot table[row sep=\\,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}] % compute a linear regression from the
    %input table
    {
        X Y\\
-700    80\\
-400    300\\
-200    300\\
-100    600\\
1       1250\\
100     1500\\
    };
    \addlegendentry{%
        $\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x
        \pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$} %
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \label{pizza_fgv}
    \end{figure}
\end{center}
```

And that Yields:

[image: Graph]

I have used Excel, and what I want LaTeX to not just plot, but to get to is the upper line of:
[image]

Comment: Please can you put a full compilable code of your question? Thank you very much.

Comment: Question: Is an exponential regression the same as a linear regression on the semi-log plot?

Comment: What? [and] no. Respectively.